# How to control a subprocess stdin, stdout, etc within Ruby?

Tags: ruby, process, fork, stdout, stdin

I'm building a small script where I'd like to launch the user's shell but redirect it's stdin and stdout so I can control them on the code. Would this be possible? I already tried with this code (which might be wrong though):

```
new_stdout, new_stdin = IO.pipe
pid = fork {
    $stdout.reopen new_stdin
    exec(ENV['SHELL'])
}

new_stdin.puts "Test"
Process.wait(pid)
```

This does nothing more than launch a new shell instance.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
IO.popen 'sh', 'r+' do |io|
  io.puts 'echo how now brown cow | tr a-z A-Z'
  result = io.gets
  p [:result, result.size, result]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

While you may just use [IO.pipe](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-c-pipe) or [Open3.popen3](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-popen3) method if simplicity is what your program requires. For advanced usage, I do it in [cognizant](https://github.com/Gurpartap/cognizant) project in the part, that you may refer to, where it demonizes a process and collects its standard input/output/error streams using Ruby 1.9's [::Process::spawn](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Process.html#method-c-spawn) manually at https://github.com/Gurpartap/cognizant/blob/master/lib/cognizant/process/execution.rb